# Does a HashMap retain the order of its elements on the next read if it is constructed and "filled" as a LinkedHashMap?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, linkedhashmap

Suppose I have a Java method that returns a HashMap  object.

Because a LinkedHashMap is a subclass of HashMap, I can return a LinkedHashMap from this method just fine.

On the next "read" action (no adding/removing/modifying of K/V pairs), would iterating over the keys of the resulting method (which returns a HashMap) go in the same order as the originating LinkedHashMap, even though the HashMap lacks the key links?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. The actual instance of the object is still the returned `LinkedHashMap`, therefore it will have its iterating order.

**However,** I wouldn't depend on this for anything. Why are you using `HashMap`s if iterating order is important? *This might be a code smell.*

Comment: Yeah, its kind of a silly question. I'm not actually using it for anything - I was just fooling around with some new ideas for a project I'm developing for and the question occurred to me. Seems like it might be useful to know the answer to at some point, though to be honest I have no idea why now.